# Meteor: how to serve images outside the /public folder?

Tags: meteor

Using Meteor I'm writing a framework that can serve custom themes in the /themes folder. I'd like the images of each theme to stay inside the corresponding theme folder.

From the Meteor documentation:

> Lastly, the Meteor server will serve any files under the public
>   directory, just like in a Rails or Django project. This is the place
>   for images, favicon.ico, robots.txt, and anything else.

How can I serve images to clients from outside the /public folder?

Comment: Maybe this question could be useful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17740790/dynamically-insert-files-into-meteor-public-folder-without-hiding-it?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

Well, you have to think of /public as the root folder when Meteor is serving its content.
So if you have content in /public/themes/x.jpg when you are referring your image in HTML you would do something like /themes/x.jpg

If I'm not understanding your question correctly, please tell me so. I will try my best to answer.

Comment: You're right, it's just that I'd like a theme to be just one folder. The problem is, a theme folder will also contain templates and css files that shouldn't be in the /public folder, as Meteor needs to be able to use them. It would be nice to have plug-and-play behaviour for themes like most CMS systems, but I'm afraid for now the only way is to separate the files into multiple folders.