# Dynamically insert files into meteor public folder without hiding it

Tags: meteor

I have a meteor application that generates images. After they are generated, I want to serve them. But each time I write to the public folder, my meteor server restarts. 
I searched for a solution and found several workarounds:

- Serve files outside of the project folder - At the moment I don't know how to achieve this, would I have to write some kind of middleware that integrates into meteor?
- Add a tilde ~ to the folder in `public/` - which seems to make meteor ignore the folder altogether, when trying to access files in the folder I get redirected to my root page.
- Run meteor in production mode. Seems like a dirty workaround for me. Right now, `meteor run --production` still restarts my server so I have to bundle my app, reinstall fibers every time, set my environment variables and then run the app. Every time I change something.

Are there any other solutions out there?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The accepted answer did not work for me, but as of version **0.6.6.3** you can do the following:

```
var fs = Npm.require('fs');
WebApp.connectHandlers.use(function(req, res, next) {
    var re = /^\/url_path\/(.*)$/.exec(req.url);
    if (re !== null) {   // Only handle URLs that start with /url_path/*
        var filePath = process.env.PWD + '/.server_path/' + re[1];
        var data = fs.readFileSync(filePath, data);
        res.writeHead(200, {
                'Content-Type': 'image'
            });
        res.write(data);
        res.end();
    } else {  // Other urls will have default behaviors
        next();
    }
});
```

#### Notes

- `process.env.PWD` will give you the project root
- if you plan to put files inside your project

  - don't use the `public` or `private` meteor folders
  - use dot folders (eg. hidden folders ex: `.uploads`)

  Not respecting these two will cause local meteor to restart on every upload, unless you run your meteor app with: `meteor run --production`

Comment: I don't fully understand how to implement this code. Where do I define the folder I want to serve? For example I create a .uploads folder inside my project root. I want to serve this at http://hostname.com/uploads. How do I do this with your code?

Comment: nevermind I got it! This is a great way to serve user specific images using meteor. The other ways made the server restart each time.

Comment: I get this error
`Error: EISDIR, illegal operation on a directory
    at Object.fs.readSync (fs.js:476:19)
    at Object.fs.readFileSync (fs.js:310:28)
    at Object.handle (app/server/server.js:159:23)
    at next (/root/.meteor/packages/webapp/f42f80024d/npm/node_modules/connect/lib/proto.js:190:15)
    at packages/fast-render/lib/server/inject.js:115
    at packages/fast-render/lib/server/fast_render.js:47`

What can the cause be?

Comment: `EISDIR`: You are trying to read a directory, instead of a file + downloading a directory/folder is not possible. Doublecheck your paths, that you read/request/serve the right thing. Note: The error occurs int `readFileSync` and the you pass the method a path to a directory.

Comment: This works very well on my development machine but I get a `Internal Server Error` when I deploy my app on meteor remote server. How do I make this work?

Comment: I used a /server/.uploads folder to serve up pdf files.  I used fs node to write and read data to this directory without a server restart.  My main issue is when you deploy Meteor ignores the folder in the bundle... so you'll have to find another way to deploy the folder structure or every time you deploy the .uploads will get erased.  Work around for that situation would be much appreciated!

Comment: Please see my SO question on this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28105957/meteor-and-the-private-directory

Comment: accepted your answer as it seems to work better with recent versions of meteor.

Answer (score 7):

It's not that easy.

- Writing to `public` is out of question, as Meteor manages this folder and thus restarts itself on every file change.
- Writing to ignored folder (starting with `.` or ending with `~`, or even outside of Meteor directory) is an option. However, you'll need to manually serve those files. A small middleware would do the trick:

```
__meteor_bootstrap__.app.stack.splice (0, 0, {
  route: '/mediaPathOfChoice',
  handle: function(req, res, next) {

    /* Read the proper file based on req.url */

    res.writeHead(200, {
      'Content-Type': /* Put the item MIME type here */
    });
    res.write(/* Put item contents here */);
    res.end();

  },

});
```

- For many publishing options, writing files on the application server is not the best solution anyway. Consider setting up a media server for your files - S3 buckets are solid and cheap for this purpose.

Answer (score 3):

So I solved this with [iron:router](https://atmospherejs.com/iron/router). I made a folder, `assets`, that's *outside* the meteor folder. I then have code like this to serve the files

```
var fs = Npm.require('fs');
var path = Npm.require('path');

Router.map(function () {
  this.route('assets', {
    where: 'server',
    path: '/assets/:filename(.*)',
    action: function() {
      var basePath = process.env.ASSET_PATH;
      var filename = path.normalize(path.join(basePath, this.params.filename));
      var res = this.response;
      if (filename.substr(0, basePath.length) != basePath ||
          !fs.existsSync(filename) ||
          !fs.statSync(filename).isFile()) {
        res.writeHead(404, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
        res.end('404: no such asset: ' + this.params.filename);
        return;
      }
      var data = fs.readFileSync(filename);
      var mimeType = mime.lookup(filename);
      res.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Type': mimeType });
      res.write(data);
      res.end();
    },
  });
});
```

Mime lookup looks like this

```
var mime = {
  lookup: (function() {

    var mimeTypes = {
      ".html": "text/html",
      ".js":   "application/javascript",
      ".json": "application/json",
      ".png":  "image/png",
      ".gif":  "image/gif",
      ".jpg":  "image/jpg",
    };

    return function(name) {
      var type = mimeTypes[path.extname(name)];
      return type || "text/html";
    };
  }()),
};
```

That code is only executed on the server so put it in the server folder or make sure it's in an `if (Meteor.isServer)` check.

As you can see above I'm using an environment variable for the path to the asset folder. So I can run meteor like this

```
ASSET_PATH=/some/path/to/assets meteor
```

I'm also using the [meteorhacks:npm](https://atmospherejs.com/meteorhacks/npm) module for the `fs` and `path` modules.

Answer (score 0):

This package may help:

CollectionFS adds simple yet robust file uploading and downloading abilities to your Meteor web app. It is a mix of Meteor.Collection and MongoDB's GridFS. CollectionFS stores files in your MongoDB database but also provides the ability to easily store files on the server filesystem or a remote filesystem.

https://github.com/CollectionFS/Meteor-CollectionFS