# Meteor upload empty files to public folder

Tags: file-upload, meteor

I'm trying to upload files in Meteor using this [great script](https://gist.github.com/dariocravero/3922137). I modified the event to handle multiple files, like this:

```
'click #saver': function(ev) {  
  $.each( $(".fileuploader"), function (index, item) {
    if(item.files.length > 0) {
    Meteor.saveFile(item.files[0], item.files[0].name);
  }
 })
}
```

Everything else is exactly the same as in the Gist (see link to script, above).

The upload shows no errors and the page reloads after the public folder is changed, but most of the files uploaded to the public folder show up as empty, (i.e. they are 0kb in size). There seems to be no pattern. Sometimes all files are empty, sometimes only a couple, and in no predictable order. The console sometimes logs correctly, and other times doesn't. Any thoughts?

Thanks, as always, for your considered advice.

db

Answer (score 0):

It's not that easy at this moment. Files in `public` dir are managed by Meteor. Therefore, whenever contents of that directory change, the server reloads itself - terminating the file save you've been inside.

The solution is to put files in a place Meteor does not care about: hidden folder (`.name`), ignored folder (`name~`), or folder outside of Meteor directory.

Then you'll need to serve those files by hand. See this answer for a snippet:

[Dynamically insert files into meteor public folder without hiding it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17740790/dynamically-insert-files-into-meteor-public-folder-without-hiding-it/17743042#17743042)

Comment: How do you include these hidden folders by hand?  When I do a deploy using Meteor-up, the folder /.name is removed from EC2 instance.  Is there a script that will include the folder structure in the deployment bundle?

Comment: Please see my SO question on this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28105957/meteor-and-the-private-directory